# Showing Value only if Condition matched in Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript

I wanted to show the list of jobs that a hr has posted in the Angular HTML. If one hr had logged in then all the jobs that he/she posted should show only to the hr page, not the jobs posted by all the hrs. I'm trying to achieve this by comparing the hrId with the HrId (used as foregin key in jobPosting) table. If both matches then the page should show all the jobs posted by that particular Hr. Hr id i'll get when the Hr Logins, and by using Local Storage access_token. Other I'll get by using one Get Method that will have all the jobs.

**Below is the code of LoadCurrentUser using Local Storage. From here I will get the Id of current HR**

```js
loadCurrentUser(){
  const token=localStorage.getItem("access_item");
  const userInfo=token != null ? this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(token):null;
  const data=userInfo ? {
    UserId:userInfo.UserId,
    UserName:userInfo.UserName,
    Email:userInfo.Email,
    City:userInfo.Company
  }:null;
  this.currentUser.next(data);
  return data;
}
```

**Get Method from both Angular and .net**

```js
getAllJobPostings():Observable<JobPosting[]>{
  return this.http.get<JobPosting[]>(this.basicURL+'Main/GetAllJobPostings');
}
```

**Get method from .net**

```
[HttpGet("GetAllJobPostings")]
public IEnumerable<JobPosting> GetDetails(){
  return Context.JobPosting.ToList();
}
```

**Model Class of Job Posting**

```js
export class JobPosting{
  jobid:number=0;
  title:string='';
  hrId:number=0;
  experience:number=0;
  position:string='';
  company:string='';
  ctc:number=0;
  skills:string='';
  description:string='';
}
```

[Database Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNXA4.png)
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WVhU.png)

If the HrId=2 matches then only that particular record should show.

Please suggest me how to achieve this, Suggest me the code.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you're stuck on? It seems like you've set up some form of access tokens, which suggests that you have the authentication and authorization side of things is taken care of on the server side. So it seems like you just need to check if the user is signed in on the server and then limit your query to returning results for that user, right?

Comment: No, it's not like that. In any Job portal website, suppose I login as a HR then I should be able to see which are the jobs I posted. In this case I wanted the same thing, like if there are multiple Person who has signed up as HR then after login they should be able to see their respective jobs they've posted not others. That access token is given after login. Suppose one HR logins then that access token will be generated and using that Id of hr, I'll verify the jobs he posted and then show all the jobs that he has posted. Hope it helps

Comment: Database result just means that if HrID=1 then the HR whose login id =1 , had posted that job. Treat both as foreign key of each other. We need a common value right, so I've provided this as a common value for comparison

Answer (score 0):

May be some of you didn't know what I was looking for, I'll simplify here. Actually I wanted to render value based on the Id of the HR, Suppose My HrID =1 then whatever the jobs I've posted should show on the HR Admin page.

**Below is the Code**

```
user:any;
  hrid:any;
  allJobDetails:JobPosting[]=[];
  
  constructor(private service:UserServiceService){};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.user=this.service.loadCurrentUser();
   
    this.getJobDetails();
  }

  getJobDetails()
  {
    this.service.getAllJobPostings().subscribe(
      (res:JobPosting[])=>
      {
       for(let r of res)
       {
        if(r.hrId == this.user.UserId)
        {
          this.hrid=r.hrId.toString();
          this.allJobDetails.push(r);
          /* this.allJobDetails=r;  -- don't do this, if you do this then you'll get 
  the error when you're trying to print using "allJobDetails" in HTMl, as this will throw the error as **typeOf(allJobDetails)** is **OBJECT** and you'll not be able to render the object in HTML.    
*/   }
       }
      }
    )
  }
```

**Below I've mentioned the code that i used in HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="user.UserId === hrid ">
    {{user|json}}

    <div *ngFor="let job of allJobDetails">
        <p>{{job.title}}</p>
        <p>{{job.company}}</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Here you'll get the expected result by just printing the values that are in the JobPosting Model Class, I've also got the expected result as I've mentioned in the Question**.